# How to prevent new line with floating divs with percentage width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to prevent new lines on floating divs with percentage widths.

```
<div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="width: 33.33%; float: left;"></div>
    <div style="width: 33.33%; float: left;"></div>
    <div style="width: 33.33%; float: left;"></div>
    <div style="width: 33.33%; float: left;"></div>
</div>
```

Desired effect: the 3 first div's would appear, but the last one would overflow the parent div and be hidden. This MUST use percentage width divs on the inner elements. Thank you.

Comment: `33.33% * 4 = 133.32%` that's going to overflow. Change `33.33%` to `25%`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek thanks. It has to be 33% and it has to be on the same line, no new line after the overflow point (ie after the 3rd div).

Comment: Alright. But what do you mean by a new line? I've made a fiddle and don't seem to have a problem with spacing: http://jsfiddle.net/BY92n/

Comment: Thanks for your help. What I need is the 4th 33% div to not be visible because its on the same line as the rest. In your example the 2 last divs wrap. I want to prevent any divs from wrapping.

Comment: @Andypandy change its CSS `display` property to "none"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BY92n/1/ is this what you want ?

Comment: Do you mean when the elements appear in the inspector of a browser?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are - [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/BY92n/16/)

```
<div class="main" style="overflow: hidden;width:100%">
    <div class="t">1</div>
    <div class="t">2</div>
    <div class="t">3</div>
    <div class="t">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In this case the element is not hidden.

Comment: And how can you see it ?
http://jsfiddle.net/BY92n/14/
here is the fiddle with different background colors

Comment: Scroll over, and you will see.

Comment: Yeah I missed that, I have edited my answer. I totally didn't see the overflow-x at bottom, thanks for pointing that.

Comment: Hm, there is still issues, for example when you move the content with arrows or scroll, guess I should work a little bit more )

Answer (score 0):

BBekyarov's answer's logic is the answer, but you will need and "overflow: hidden;" on the body too if you want the 4th div to be actually hidden, otherwise you have a horizontal scroll which leads to the "4" or whatever there is inside the last div.

Upadted on his jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/BY92n/11/

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="t">1</div>
    <div class="t">2</div>
    <div class="t">3</div>
    <div class="t">4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden; 
}
.t{
    width:33.33%;
    background-color:gray;
    display:table-cell;
}
.main{
    display:table;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: It's not hidden, just off the page. `display:table-cell;` is why it is not hiding the element.

Comment: Without it, the 4th div wont overflow but fall on the next row instead.